# How can I find somebody to chat about papers?

Tags: publications, online-resource, journal-clubs

I’m a computer-science PhD student. I want to find people to chat about papers (by others) online. How can I go about this?

I was looking into the chat of this website. I was also looking at some IRC channels.

Comment: Heard of "reading clubs" for people to do novels etc but papers? new one on me, possibly because most students doing PhD's read different papers.

Comment: You could organize a paper reading group with the people from your lab. Each meeting has a different moderator who picks a paper (which should be interesting to the group). I have made good experiences with that kind of set-up.

Comment: If you want to do something like this, it’s probably best to do it locally. I created a group in my department where graduate students can present on anything they feel like - paper, concepts, non-academic things, etc so that students can get comfortable talking out loud to their peers. Perhaps you could do something similar, but you may be hard pressed to find people that want to converse about the same papers as you do, for that, I feel like a conference is probably best - or go to Twitter.

Answer (score 3):

Ask your supervisor and other people at your institute if something like this already exists, maybe you can join an existing group.

If it doesn't exist yet, maybe you can get their endorsement and assistance to set one up. It could help if they spread the word a bit even if they don't have time to join themselves.

Another avenue to explore is Meetup, trying out a variety of keywords in your field. Although that might end up being a bit more industry. Which doesn't have to be bad, if you had thoughts about going into industry after your PhD.